# Page redirection when changing value in dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which creates a dropdown list.
When the user selects an item, I want to call a certain action in a controller and pass the new value as a parameter.

I have the following code, but this does not work and I get "Invalid regular expression C" when I check with Firebug.

```
            @Html.DropDownList(
                "ctrlName", 
                items, 
                null,
                new { onchange = "document.location.href = /Controller/Action/this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing quotes in js

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ctrlName", 
    items, 
    null,
    new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Controller/Action/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

Comment: small addition: please use window.location instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857878/window-location-vs-document-location

Answer (score 1):

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("ctrlName", new[]{
    new SelectListItem { Text="--Select--", Value="" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "KodefuGuru", Value = "Create" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "PlatinumBay", Value = "PlatinumBay" }
    },
    null,
    new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Controller/Action/'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;)" })%>
```