# window.location vs. document.location

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, window, document

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between window.location and document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip)

In JavaScript, both `window` and `document` have a `location` property, and by setting both to a different URL, browser loads the new URL.

What's the difference between them?