# document.location does not change the webpage in IE9?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to redirect to a different page in IE9 (9.0.3).

When I try to get/set `document.location`, or `document.location.href`, or `window.location`/`window.location.href`, I'm unable to do so. It fails without giving any errors.

I've tried to check whether the document and windows objects are set, and they are, so I have no idea why the location object is "missing".

I tried getting the `document.URL` and that works fine, but it's read-only.

Anyone know what the problem is or how to achieve this in a cross-browser way?

Comment: I believe this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857878/window-location-vs-document-location

Comment: It works fine for here. Can you show some relevant code?

Answer (score 8):

I was also experiencing the same problem but found that adding

```
window.event.returnValue = false;
```

above line in the javascript before the redirection resolved the problem.

Comment: Holy cow.This is the solution . Gr8 work dinga. Seriously would hv gifted you something - this problem has been driving me crazy for the past 1 week

Comment: Fixes ie9 but breaks Firefox

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/c864ae63-66f6-4656-bcae-86b0018d70c9

Apparently it's a caching bug, you can solve it by appending a timestamp to the destination URL (that is, using a "unique" URL every time).

Comment: Note that the guy in this post is doing something weird.  He submits a form to (somepage) then he redirects to (somepage) - the same page.  Why he didn't just submit the form without ajax idk.  I think the "caching issue" is specific to this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your IE9 has some security restrictions in place that prevent JavaScript from directing URL's. window.location.href = "" should work normally on IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Cache may be the reason, try:

```
location.href='something.php?tmp=' + Date.parse(new Date())
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute URL:

> var url = '/section/page/';
>   var host = window.location.hostname;
>   window.location = 'http://' + host + url;

Where url is the relative path to your page.