# page not redirecting in chrome and FF but in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am calling a javascript from within a iframe to redirect to another url.

```
var new_url  = "http://mysite.com/?language=en&origin="
                    + origin +"&destination="+ destination +                    "&Date=" + date;
    }
    //window.location.replace(new_url);
    window.top.location.href = new_url;
    //window.location.assign(new_url);
```

purpose is to open the page out of iframe within same window so i am using

```
window.top.location.href = new_url;
```

It is working finr in IE but not in chrome and FF though not giving any error also

Comment: Are you sure `window.location` wouldn't work in this case (i don't use iframes much, but the window variable should still be the same, correct?)? Also `top.window` should select the topmost window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209214/document-location-href-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: If I got your question correctly, `window.location.href = new_url` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest browsers have [strict rules](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/frames/navigation/) and do not allow to change, only if:

1. The locations of A and B have the same origin, which is to say they
   have the same scheme, host, and port (HTTP, stackoverflow.com, 80
   for example), or
2. B is a top-level window, and A is a window in a frame nested at some depth within B (direct child, child of a child, etc.), or
3. B is a window opened using window.open and A can change the location of the window that opened B (so B is a popup opened by A, by a popup window opened by A, or at greater depth), or
4. B isn't a top-level window, but its parent window, or its parent's parent window, or at some similar amount of parentage the locations of that window and A are same-origin

Answer (score 1):

Try only this, top is not required.

```
window.location.href = new_url;
```

Comment: window is referred to the iframe but window.top referred to the main window

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use window.location.href for your case.

But I thought of explaining the difference between the two.

window.location.href returns the location of the current page.

top.location.href (which is an alias of window.top.location.href) returns the location of the topmost window in the window hierarchy. If a window has no parent, top is a reference to itself (in other words, window === window.top).

top is useful both when you're dealing with frames and when dealing with windows which have been opened by other pages. For example, if you have a page called test.html with the following script:

```
var newWin=window.open('about:blank','test','width=100,height=100');
newWin.document.write('<script>alert(top.location.href);</script>');
```

The resulting alert will have the full path to test.html – not about:blank, which is what window.location.href would return.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have just added

```
window.event.returnValue = false;
```

before redirecting and it's working in all browsers

Comment: but only by adding this line, code is working for me in chrome as well