# Button works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, button, hyperlink

So I know absolutely nothing about HTML and im editing my site

I managed to create a button that opens a link

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'http://gotlinks.co/5Vvl';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Click me to Verify!</button>
```

But it only works in firefox and not chrome, someone please help me

Comment: Look into the `<a> ` tag

Comment: Im not going to google it for you.... you can do this yourself.

Comment: also in chrome when it doesnt work it just adds this to the end of the url "?#"

Answer (score 0):

Try this basic code .

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton" class="float-left
         submit-button" >Click me to Verify!</button>

         <script> 
             function myFunction() {
                  window.location.href = "http://gotlinks.co/5Vvl"; 
             } 
         </script>
```

Comment: okay I was really happy because it was working in chrome but now if I go to the site in firefox it immediatly redirects me to that link test it "thegemgenerator.com" in firefox

Comment: yeah , look same @trkh

Comment: If not same try this one in function myFunction

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton" class="float-left
         submit-button" >Click me to Verify!</button>

         <script> 
             function myFunction() {
                  window.location= "http://gotlinks.co/5Vvl"; 
             } 
         </script>                                                                                                               changed it to this and the same problem

Answer (score 0):

use window.location.href instead

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'http://gotlinks.co/5Vvl';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Click me to Verify!</button>
```

Comment: @trkh Could you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209214/document-location-href-not-working-in-chrome ?

Comment: <button onclick="window.event.returnValue = false; window.location.href = 'http://gotlinks.co/5Vvl';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Click me to Verify!</button>