# JavaScript - how to parse hash parameters from url?

Tags: javascript

How do you get a part of a URL hash using js?

Here is what I have:

`something.html?il=#/new/product/123`

And I need to get "123" as a variable ...

***no libraries, pure javascript please.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Although if the URL actually looks like that the value is in `window.location.hash`.

Comment: With that `#` in place as you have it, that's part of the URL _hash_, not the querystring!

Comment: As @MichaelBerkowski says, this is not the querystring. Either you've made a mistake in the design or terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need the hash, not the querystring. Anything after the # is called the hash of the url.

You can use document.location.hash and parse that string

```
var id = document.location.hash.split("/"); //convert the hash into an array, splitting with "/"
id = id.pop(); //pop will get the last item on the array
```

However readable and easy this method is, its not safe to assume the string you are searching will always be the last on the array. You could use a regular expression to further narrow the chances

```
var hash = document.location.hash,
    re = /\/new\/product\/(d+)/,
    id = hash.match(re);// for some reason this matches both the full string and the number
id = id.pop(); // so I must do this again
```

Comment: `window.location` is safer than `document.location`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857878/window-location-vs-document-location

Comment: @turibe in my example I'm not trying to set the location to something different so it even makes more sense to use document location instead of window location (which is read/write in all browsers while document.location is not). Anyway, I'm just learning about this difference so thanks for pointing it out, I guess..

Answer (score 4):

Here is some Javascript that should help you. Just take the return value from the getQuerystringNameValue() function and use $("#textboxID").val(returnValue); to assign it to the textbox.

```
alert("name1" + " = " + getQuerystringNameValue("name1"));
alert("name2" + " = " + getQuerystringNameValue("name2"));
alert("name3" + " = " + getQuerystringNameValue("name3"));


function getQuerystringNameValue(name)
{
    // For example... passing a name parameter of "name1" will return a value of "100", etc.
    // page.htm?name1=100&name2=101&name3=102

    var winURL = window.location.href;
    var queryStringArray = winURL.split("?");
    var queryStringParamArray = queryStringArray[1].split("&");
    var nameValue = null;

    for ( var i=0; i<queryStringParamArray.length; i++ )
    {           
        queryStringNameValueArray = queryStringParamArray[i].split("=");

        if ( name == queryStringNameValueArray[0] )
        {
            nameValue = queryStringNameValueArray[1];
        }                       
    }

    return nameValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `document.location.search` contains the query parameters. You can use [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info) to parse out the pieces you need. However, in the URL in your example, it isn't the query string, it's the anchor, found in `document.location.hash`.