# javascript click event not working in div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div in my page that is showing X at top of modal, I like to by clicking this user redirect to homepage. I tried this but the even is not firing at all.

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close" onclick="redirecttologin()">x</div>
......
  </div
```

this is java script but even the alert is not showing

```
 function redirecttologin() {
  alert("test");
document.location.href = "/";
 };
```

I am sure that it has the reference to java script file as other things are working in page.

*problem was class="close".

Comment: Are there any errors showing in your browser console?

Comment: Post more code.

Comment: Check your console `<F12>`...

Comment: Maybe another element is covering the 'x' and preventing the click from being triggered on it

Comment: Is that `</div` by mistake or is it missing `>` in real?

Comment: `redirecttologin` is probably undefined in the context you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work properly, the only issue is that you should use `window.location` instead of `document.location`. They are both the same, but as documentation says, the `document.location` is read only property.

Also notice, that your closing `<div>` tag is missing `>`. That might be a problem as well.

```js
function redirecttologin() {
  alert("test");
  window.location.href = "/";
};
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="close" onclick="redirecttologin()">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use

```
window.location.href = "/"
```

Comment: [`document.location`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857878/window-location-vs-document-location) should work in most browsers.